# NoSuchElement exceptions

Tags: java

I am currently working throw the Helsinki MOOC for OOP Java and I am currently experiencing an issue that from a scanner object. Here is a SS of the error that my compiler keeps throwing.

[image]

I searched previous posts with a similar error and they all seem to come from File streams rather than standard input. Here is the method in question that give me issues:

```
public void run() {
    int turns = playerMoves;

    while (turns > 0) {
        System.out.println(turns + "\n");
        showEntities();
        makeDungeon();

        if (vampires.size() == 0) {
            break;
        }

        String command = reader.nextLine();

        logic.moveEntity(player, command);

        if (vampiresCanMove) {
            logic.moveRandomly(vampires, command.length());
        }

        turns--;
    }

    if (turns > 0) {
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    } else {
        System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass command to logic.moveEntity, but then you pass command length to logic.moveRandomly?

Comment: Maybe it's a seed for the randomness. Anyway. I feel like we need more context on where `reader` comes from.

Comment: The reader comes from an object var but I have also created a local scanner object within the run() method but to no avail.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error here directly instead of the screen shot? Also tell us which line in your code causes the error.

Comment: And read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ ... who on earth upvotes a question with a screenshot?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your example really looks like you're trying to read the next line from somewhere in that call to `reader.nextLine()` - except there are no more lines to read...  Is your input source somehow including fewer lines than the number in `playerMoves` ?